# Mongodb : AutoReconnect, Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i use pymongo to test the performance of the mongodb.
i use 100 threads, every thread excecute 5000 insert, and everything work ok.
but when i excecute 10000 insert in every thead,  i meet some error:

**"AutoReconnect: Connection reset by peer"**

Answer (score 1):

Driver can't remove dropped socket from connection from pool until your code try use it.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly needs to be done to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is your plateform ? ( simple mongod, ReplicaSet, Shard)

Do you use "bulk insert" ? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts

Comment: I faced this error and I'm using bulk insert in simple MongoDB.